# Angular cli ignore files for minification

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When i create a production build, the client minifies all files.

I would like for the client to exclude a specific file where i can place the endpoint variables.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how and why these would be set? Would you an API endpoint for QA and another one for PROD? Would there be multiple variations for each environment, or just one for each environment? Is this something that can be handled with the Environment files? Did you try adding a JS file with the variable to the angular-cli.json "scripts" array?

Comment: Basically i have a Settings.ts with many static variables with endpoints for the web api. Whenever i build into prod i would like this file to be unchanged so the client can change the endpoints to match their environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution would be to move this file out of the angular-cli pipeline. Rename it to settings.js and place it in your assets folder.

In this file expose the endpoint as a property on the DOM window global: window.ENDPOINT = '/some/end/point'

Add this file to the scripts array in the angular-cli.json

In your application bring in the endpoint from window.ENDPOINT

Please consider the security implication of this. If any attacker can inject a script into your app they will have the ability to change the endpoint.

**Update**

Another option would be to add them to a json file in in your assets directory.

Example: assets/settings.json

```
{
  "endpoint": "http://someUrl"
}
```

When your application starts, make a request for `/assets/settings.json` and then set the application API endpoint.

Alternatively you could allow your client to build from source after they update the endpoint `ng build --prod`

A fourth option would be: if your client has a static number of endpoints (dev,  qa, uat, prod) you can store them in the environment files and automate building (and delivering a build) for each environment.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. Since you deem this solution to be dangerous, can you recommend any other option where you handle your app to the client and he is able to modify the endpoints as he wishes?

Comment: Great answer. Thank you for making sense of such an ambiguous question :)

Comment: This didn't work for me -it still included the file from assets into the minified /compressed code - and referenced that instead of the file inside assets

Comment: Yes, non solution and having multiple builds defeats the purpose of a release pipeline